# How to create a modular class for barcode scanning using Firebase ML Kit

Tags: java, android, firebase, barcode-scanner, firebase-mlkit

I want to create a modular class that I can use anytime I want to scan a barcode. Is this possible using Firebase ML Kit?

This is what I've got so far:

```
public List<FirebaseVisionBarcode> ScanBarcode(int... barcodeFormats)
{
    //region Init, config and execution of the barcode scanning
    final FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder BUILDER =
            new FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder();

    //Set barcode formats based on arguments
    for (int formats : barcodeFormats)
    {
        BUILDER.setBarcodeFormats(formats);
    }

    final FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions OPTIONS = BUILDER.build();

    final FirebaseVisionImage IMAGE = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);

    final FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector DETECTOR = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
            .getVisionBarcodeDetector(OPTIONS);

    DETECTOR.detectInImage(IMAGE)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionBarcode> _barcodes)
                {
                    barcodes = _barcodes;
                }
            })

            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                {
                    barcodes = new ArrayList<>();
                }
            });

    //endregion

    return barcodes;
```

Mostly taken from https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/

The problem here is that the listener, for the `DETECTOR`, is some kind of async call. Which means that it will return before `onSuccess` is called.

The barcode scanning part works, but I'm having a hard time wrapping it in a class of it's own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Not sure if it's the best approach class structure wise, but it works quite nice.

```
public Task<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>> ScanBarcode(int... barcodeFormats)
{
    //region Init, config and execution of the barcode scanning. Mostly taken from https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/
    final FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder BUILDER =
            new FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder();

    //Set barcode formats based on arguments
    for (int formats : barcodeFormats)
    {
        BUILDER.setBarcodeFormats(formats);
    }

    final FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions OPTIONS = BUILDER.build();

    final FirebaseVisionImage IMAGE = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);

    final FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector DETECTOR = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
            .getVisionBarcodeDetector(OPTIONS);

    final Task<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>> DETECT_IMG_TASK = DETECTOR.detectInImage(IMAGE)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionBarcode> _barcodes)
                {
                    barcodes = _barcodes;
                }
            })

            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                {
                    barcodes = new ArrayList<>();
                }
            });

    return DETECT_IMG_TASK;
    //endregion

}

public List<FirebaseVisionBarcode> GetBarcodes()
{
    return barcodes;
}
```

`detectInImage` returns a `Task`. What I did was return this task. Once this task completes, you can call `GetBarcodes` to obtain the parsed data. I hate to force calling additional methods to get the final results, but it was the only way I could get it to work.